# Replacing empty select boxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, replace, each

I'm trying to replace all my empty select boxes with a text message but it's not working.  Here's my jQuery:

```
var s = $("table.preference select option");
if(s.length == 0){
   s.parents("td").html("No more preferences to add!");
}
```

I've also tried:

```
$("table.preference select option").each(function(){
   if($(this).length == 0){
      $(this).parents("td").html("No more preferences to add!");
   }
});
```

But neither works.  I have two `select` tags in two different tables - I need the jQuery to find any empty select box and replace its table cell with a text message.  Does anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by select box? Do you mean [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)?

Comment: Are you sure there is really no more `<option>` inside your `<select>`? This is different from having an `<option>` with blank text/value

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified it was a markup tag. And yeah, my PHP isn't feeding any `option` tags into the `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach will not work if you have at least 1 option-element in one of all select-elements inside the table.

Solution without using $.each():

```
 $("table.preference select:not(:has(option))")
  .parents("td").html("No more preferences to add!");
```

Comment: i like this approach - correct me if I'm wrong, would it also work with `$(table.preference select:empty)`

Comment: @kaveman: yes, `:empty` will work too if there is really nothing inside(no textNodes, no optgroup). A single whitespace will break `:empty`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("table.preference select").each(function() {
    if ($(this).children("option").length === 0) {
      $(this).parents("td").html("No more preferences to add!");
    }
});
```

Based on @Kon's suggestion, if you wish to check inside possible `optgroup` tags as well, you could try this:

```
$("table.preference select").each(function() {
    if ($("option", this).length === 0) {
      $(this).parents("td").html("No more preferences to add!");
    }
});
```

That will check for `options` inside the `select` itself, as well as inside any `optgroups`.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/UEaQU/1/

Comment: No need to filter children, because the only valid child of `select` is `option`.

Comment: @Kon - `optgroup` is also valid inside a select.

Comment: Karl, touche.. I forgot about optgroup.  Though if you have optgroups, then your code would never find any options even if they existed, because `children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$("table.preference select").each(function(){
   if($(this).children().length == 0) {
      $(this).parents("td").html("No more preferences to add!");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried other selectors? Off the top of my head:

```
var s =  $("table.preference select:empty");
if(s.length != 0){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

- Detect any Select Box with Empty Options.
- Filter any div that contains some text "abc"

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epJ2K/2/)

---

```
    $("div>select:not(:has(option))").hide();

$('div').filter(function () {
    if($(this).text().trim().toLowerCase() === 'abc'){
        $(this).hide();
    };
})
```